# How do I ensure IBM Mobilefirst 6.3 allows caching?

Tags: browser-cache, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm building an application using MobileFirst version 6.3, and I'm noticing that every request for anything is indicating in the request header: `Cache-Control:max-age=0`

I'm not setting this anywhere explicitly. Does anyone know why this is happening, and what I can do to enable the static files in my application to be cached?

Reformed question:

I want to make sure my mobilewebapp built in 6.3 is properly caching using normal browser methods ( and not utilizing the MF application-cache feature ). When my app loads, ALL files load using the cache-control and pragma headers:

Request Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie: <cookie stuff>
Host:blahblah.com
Referer:https://<blahblah>/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
```

When I inspect the network response from the Chrome developer tools, no files appear to be coming from cache ( noted by it not saying 'from cache' anywhere on that tab ).

This is applying to all files being requested:

index.html, worklight.js, wljq.js, all of my custom js...

I've noticed the cache-control: max-age=0 in the request headers for every file requested on page load. How do I change this to allow my application to cache?

Second Edit:

Application cache has been suggested, but we also need to support IE9... so this forces us to use regular caching due to no support for it in IE9.

Comment: You are missing a lot of explanations. By request do you mean adapter request? what does this has to do with "static files" then?

Comment: I mean any HTTP request. Therefore getting any of the JS or CSS is sending the Cache-Control:max-age=0 request header. I'm not sure where or how I control this.

Comment: Still not a proper explanation...

Comment: Updated question above.

Comment: What environment are you testing this for? Android? Mobile web?

Comment: We're only doing mobile web at this time.

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst provides a **standards-based** manifest support for the Desktop Browser and Mobile Web environments; this allows caching of data as requested in the question.

You need to use the feature as described in the user documentation: [Managing the application Cache Manifest in MobileFirst Studio](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_appcache_procedure.html)

Comment: We aren't using the application cache feature, because it doesn't work for our infrastructure architecture. We're trying to use standard browser caching... which is controlled by the HTTP request/response headers.

Comment: This might be a question about setting the cache-control headers on the Liberty profile server we're using. Is there a way to modify the response headers on what is returned by the Liberty profile server?  Does this sound feasible?